# Isolate names from a combined name cell in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, concatenation

I'm trying to use a combination of substring, instr, and charindex, to consistently get the names from a combined string value formatted as follows:
`"Lastname,Firstname MiddleName"`

I have to be able to take into consideration the following logic:

1. Some names (first, middle, last inclusive) are hyphenated.
2. There isn't anything but a space separating the first and middle names.
3. You don't have to have a middle name.

Here's what I have so far

```
,SUBSTRING(p.Name,1,INSTR(p.Name,',',1) - 1) as "Patient Surname"
,SUBSTRING(p.Name,INSTR(p.Name,' ',1) + 1, INSTR(p.Name,' ')) as "Patient Middle Name"  
,SUBSTRING(p.Name,INSTR(p.Name,',',1) + 1, INSTR(p.Name,' ')) as "Patient First Name"
```

I've also tried things like this to get first name.

```
,SUBSTRING(p.Name,charindex('','',p.Name)+1, charindex(',',reverse(p.Name))) as "Patient First Name"
```

I seem to be confident about the surname.
The first name and middle name are what I'm struggling to capture. Can anyone help?

Here are a few sample names I have to work with.

- Bear,BooBoo Brown
- Test,Edis Female
- Kgh-cdr,Cyan Crayon
- Kghcdr,Amber B
- Raptors,Toronto Basket
- Pcstest,Chart Review
- Medrec,Test-man One
- St. Smurf,Baker
- Fruit,Red Delicious-yum
- Fruit,Green-apple Apple-sauce
- Fruit,Green Grape
- ZZSivagnanasundaram,TestLongName Testingmiddlename
- Fish,Blue One
- Fish,Test Pastella
- Smurf,Lazy Bones
- Fruit,Pomegranate Red
- Fruit,Pomegranate New
- O'Fruit,Banana Too
- Boat,Row Your
- Fruit,Mango Second

Comment: What if someone does NOT have a middle name? This assumes they do...

Comment: Updated that condition. Thanks!

Comment: so there is no space if there is no middle name?  You'd could code a CASE and check if there are any spaces after the comma, then if not make middle name NULL

Comment: in this case, the only one that my code seems to care about is St. Smurf,Baker  - but I think I've got that covered by looking for the space after the , character - stuff like hyphens don't matter, because I'm not looking for it, it might as well by any character other than space and comma

Comment: What you are trying to do is essentially impossible. As soon as you find a solution for the current data something else will come along and break it. Also, you might want to take a peek at this. https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @SEAN - there can only be so many 'problems' - it was likely devised as a mis-think, I agree, maybe they are converting a system - using a cursor with an error trap, then fix exceptions is one idea.

Comment: @Cato even fixing data it is nearly impossible to get this correct with t-sql. Using regex would be a better solution. Of course, the best solution would be to fix the table structure and not store multiple data points in a single column which violates 1NF. My guess is the sample data is not all of the pattern examples.

Comment: @SeanLange you're right in that there can always be some oddities. It blows my mind that we're capturing full names into one string in our main data system. This has been a headache.

Comment: @sean - regex seems to often become very complicated without being watertight - I'm happy if people like using that though.  I agree the data is in the wrong format, but if they do want to get it out of that format, they probably need some sort of code to break it up for them.

Comment: @Cato you're right. And it's a vendor's system so we can't control the code to it, unfortunately.

Comment: @Cato yes exactly. Regex is not always perfect, especially for names which are all over the place. This kind of thing will take several passes to even get close. First pass captures the bulk (~90%), then several additional passes capturing the strange outliers.

Comment: @Frantumn I feel your pain and don't envy you trying to parse this disaster out. Always blows my mind how horrible so much third party software is some of the basics like this. >.<

Comment: What about people with more that 1 middle name, my mother has 3 and I know of a guy with at least 9 who was named after a football team? Of course, there are a few people with just one name too, e.g. Prince, Cher and Pele.

Comment: It's a strange system limitation @Jodrell but essentially everything after the comma is given names, the first of which would be seen as the first given name. Everything after the first space after the first name could fall into a middle name category. If the first name is hyphenated, it would still be first name. E.g. `Lastname,First-Name Middle Name More Middle Name`

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @x as varchar(100) = 'Dinsmore,Archibald Hector';

SELECT LEFT(@x, CHARINDEX(',', @x) -1 ) as surname,
                SUBSTRING(@x, 
                            CHARINDEX(',', @x) + 1, 
                            CHARINDEX(' ',  @x, CHARINDEX(',', @X)) - CHARINDEX(',', @x) - 1
                        )  as FirstName,
                        SUBSTRING(@x, 
                                  CHARINDEX(' ',  @x, CHARINDEX(',', @X)) + 1  , 
                                  CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@X))) as middleName
```

ok this below also handles middle name

```
declare @x as varchar(100) = 'Dinsmore,Archibald';

SELECT  CHARINDEX(' ',  @x, CHARINDEX(',', @X))

SELECT LEFT(@x, CHARINDEX(',', @x) -1 ) as surname,

                CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',  @x, CHARINDEX(',', @X)) > 0 THEN
                SUBSTRING(@x, 
                            CHARINDEX(',', @x) + 1, 
                            CHARINDEX(' ',  @x, CHARINDEX(',', @X)) - CHARINDEX(',', @x) - 1
                        )  
                ELSE                            
                        RIGHT(@x, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@X)) - 1)  
                END as FirstName,

                        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',  @x, CHARINDEX(',', @X)) > 0 THEN
                        SUBSTRING(@x, CHARINDEX(' ',  @x, CHARINDEX(',', @X)) + 1  , CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@X))) 
                        ELSE
                          NULL
                          END   as middleName
```

Comment: this breaks if there is no middle name

Comment: Thanks, but i get error: `<Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function>`

Comment: @frantumn what's the input string?  I tested with your exact input string in the Q

Comment: @whatsthepoint - thanks - this sort of thing will be susceptible to any oddity of data, so any name with spaces in it or malformed data - it will be difficult!

Comment: @Cato yeah I was testing cases like that, but in an ideal world you'd like to thing any oddities are dealt with before going in to the DB (for example if you add a space after the middle name it only returns the first letter of the middle name)

Comment: Thank you all for helping me sort this out. I've provided a few examples of potential name formats to my OP.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code :

```
declare @string varchar(500)

set @string = 'Lastname,Firstname Middlename'

declare @pos int,
        @data Nvarchar(250)
set @pos=2

set @data =(
select x.i.value('.','varchar(250)') as data 
from 
(
 select CONVERT(XML,'<i>'+REPLACE(@string,',','</i><i>')+'</i>') as data 
)x1 
cross apply data.nodes('i[position()=sql:variable("@pos")]')  as x(i))

select @data as data, 
REPLACE(@data, SUBSTRING(@data, CHARINDEX(' ', @data), len(@data)+1-CHARINDEX(' ', @data)),'') FirstName,
SUBSTRING(@data, CHARINDEX(' ', @data), len(@data)+1-CHARINDEX(' ', @data)) MiddleName
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is simplest solution. I use "trick" by adding space at the end
and then we have only one case where first, middle, and last names exists :)

```
SELECT
B.Name, SUBSTRING(B.Name,1,CHARINDEX(',', B.Name) - 1) as "Patient Surname"
,SUBSTRING(B.Name,CHARINDEX(' ', B.Name + ' ') + 1, CHARINDEX(' ', B.Name + ' ')) as "Patient Middle Name"  
,SUBSTRING(B.Name, CHARINDEX(',', B.Name) + 1, CHARINDEX(' ', B.Name + ' ') - CHARINDEX(',', B.Name)) as "Patient First Name"  
FROM
(
SELECT
'Lastname,Firstname MiddleName' AS Name
UNION
SELECT
'Lastname,Firstname' AS Name  
) B
```

test on sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/27064/0

**UPDATE**
after you have added sample data
especially this record where space is in the surname

```
INSERT INTO P(Name) VALUES('St. Smurf,Baker');
```

i have modified answer

```
SELECT
P.Name, SUBSTRING(P.Name,1,CHARINDEX(',', P.Name) - 1) as "Patient Surname"
,SUBSTRING(P.Name, CHARINDEX(' ', P.Name + ' ', CHARINDEX(',', P.Name)) + 1, CHARINDEX(' ', P.Name + ' ', CHARINDEX(',', P.Name))) as "Patient Middle Name"  
,SUBSTRING(P.Name, CHARINDEX(',', P.Name) + 1, CHARINDEX(' ', P.Name + ' ', CHARINDEX(',', P.Name)) - CHARINDEX(',', P.Name)) as "Patient First Name"  
FROM
P
```

result on your sample data on sqlfiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e525d/4/0